# How to add a NullableBooleanField to an existing Django database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a database with some data. I put these data into a JSON file (`C:\Python25\python manage.py dumpdata > initial_data.json`).

Then I added added following field to one of my models:

```
visible = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)
```

When I ran `C:\Python25\python manage.py syncdb`, it produced `DatabaseError: Could not load opinions.Topic(pk=1): no such column: visible` error message upon the attempt to import data from `initial_data.json`.

How can I add a nullable boolean field to an existing database without losing the data?

**Update 1:** Apparently, I'm not the first person to run into this problem. Which database migration mechanism is better - [Django Evolution](https://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/), [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html) or something else?

Comment: South is not actually being added to the Django core. It so happens that the same developer who does South developed migrations for Django but he did them pretty much from scratch. He will however have migration notes on how to convert from south to Django migrations when Django 1.7 is released with them.

Comment: @miki725 - good to know, thanks for the correction.  Rewritten for accuracy: South is the most popular third-party migration tool, and it's what I'd use.  It is also possible to manually alter your tables, but that's much less maintainable.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper When DjangoCon 2013 videos are released you can watch the "Everybody Loves Migrations" talk by Andrew Godwin (http://www.djangocon.us/schedule/presentation/16/). It will give quite a few more details on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking here are db migrations. `syncdb` is probably a terrible management command name since it actually does not synchronize the db but only creates tables.

Currently the de-facto Django migrations standard is [South](http://south.aeracode.org/). It allows to do these things called migrations which essentially synchronize your models with the db without loosing any of the data. Introducing South to your project will allow you to add/alter/rename/remove fields or tables altogether without dealing with fixtures. If you are new to South, it has really good docs so you should have no issues following the tutorial. The only caveat I can see is that you are using Windows which might be an issue (not sure).

For now you should use South however Andrew Godwin who is a developer of South and a Django core developer, he actually is working on introducing db migrations directly into Django. This project is almost complete and has already been merged with Django master branch at Github. It will be released with Django 1.7 which is scheduled to be sometime in early 2014. So for now use South however starting with Django 1.7 you will be able to do db migrations directly in Django.